# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln(1+n \cdot |x|^n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to know for which values this series 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln(1+n \cdot |x|^n)$$ converges.

For $|x|>1$

$ \lim_{n\rightarrow + \infty} \ln(1+n \cdot |x|^n)=  + \infty \Rightarrow$ the given series diverges.

For $|x|=1$

$ \lim_{n\rightarrow + \infty} \ln(1+n \cdot |x|^n)=  
\lim_{n\rightarrow + \infty} \ln(1+n ) = + \infty \Rightarrow$ the given series diverges.

For $|x|<1$

$ \lim_{n\rightarrow + \infty} \ln(1+n \cdot |x|^n)=  
\lim_{n\rightarrow + \infty} \ln(1 ) = 0$
 And the given series converges.

Is it right?

Comment: What operation do you mean by using $\star$?  Multiplication?  Please use either `\cdot`, or juxtaposition for that purpose.

Comment: You're mostly correct. The first two points are correct; however, $\lim a_n = 0$ does not imply $\sum a_n$ converges. The typical example is $a_n = 1/n$. Obviously $a_n \to 0$, but the sum would be the harmonic series, known to diverge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $|x|\geq 1$ you are correct, but the case $|x|<1$ needs a more careful approach. Note that as $n\to +\infty$, we have that
$$\ln(1+n|x|^n)\sim n|x|^n.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: yes, I think. Applying the root test  the limit is $|x|<1$ and the series converges.